# JavaScript Real Time Calculation

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, real-time-updates

I have built a table with custom inputs numbers with [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). The Input type is gone once you put the value

I need to find a JavaScript Real Time Calculation which automatically makes the amount of my values.

I have found 2 interesting examples very suitable for my case but there is the possibility to achieve it the same without using the form and inputs?

[First example](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/VkCgh/)

[Second example](http://javalearning-adventure.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/javascript-real-time-calculation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. As you know a div element can be accessed by `document.getElementById('div_id')` and its value can be accessed by `document.getElementById('div_id').value`.

So take out the form and insert an `id` for the `div`'s that you need and access the value and then find the sum and then set the value as the `sum` to another `div`. Here is the code

```
<script>
   function calculateBMI() {

   var wtStr =document.getElementById('w').value;

   if (!wtStr)
     wtStr = '0';

   var htStr = document.getElementById('h').value;
   if (!htStr)
     htStr = '0';


   var weight = parseFloat(wtStr);
   var height = parseFloat(htStr);
   document.getElementById("r").value = weight + height;
 }
 </script>

 <input id = "w" type="Text"  name="weight" size="4" onkeyup="calculateBMI()"> Weight  (in Kilos)  
 <input id = "h" type="Text" name="height" size="4" onkeyup="calculateBMI()"> Height (in Centimeters)<br>
 <input id = "r" type="Text" name="BodyMassIndex" id="BodyMassIndex" size="4"> BMI     
 <input type="button" style="font-size: 8pt" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateBMI()" name="button">
```

​and if you don't want `input` you can use `textarea`.

Comment: Ok i am going to try as you have explained, the thing is i dont need to use Input and Textarea, i am using Jquery editable and my Input is gone once i edit the html, so that's why i need to find a different solution

Comment: Thanks Emil, i found what i was looking for http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/187238/collect-sum-of-a-column-in-a-html-table