# Pass text within a div (number) through calculation in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For lack of a better title, I'm looking to take the example I have in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stebesplace/gYf4h/7/), and convert it to pull the number that's within a div (it will always be a number):

```
<div class="output" id="i1">100</div>
```

And pass that number through a formula, to spit it out in real time to a **p** tag (doesn't need to be a p tag, could be another div.

```
<p>200</p> or <div id="i2">200</div>
```

Where the 200 above, is calculated by adding the original value of the div id #i1, plus 100. Right now, the fiddle shows that when you enter in a value for the input, it spits out the real time calculation.

So the question is, what would it look like where instead of an input value, the function would be pulling the numerical data out of the DIV tag, running it through a function, and spitting it back out into a paragraph tag? I think the bulk of it is completed functionality wise, but can't quite figure out the pulling from DIV text.

Some posts I've looked at already include [this one about real time inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892120/javascript-real-time-calculation), [this one on calculations and displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913367/pulling-through-text-into-div), and a few others on here.

**SOLUTION**

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stebesplace/gYf4h/10/) shows the solution for me. It's far simpler than I had before. There was a solution given below regarding a listener plugin, which looked pretty good, but way overkill for what I needed.

Comment: @KevinBoucher You don't see the question mark? jk

Comment: The question is, what is the question?

Comment: why do you bind 2 event handlers for the same event. why not just combine it into one . http://jsfiddle.net/gYf4h/8/

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replying. The question was how to take what I've prototyped, with input fields, and a p tag output, to take the input from content within a DIV, instead of an input field, and still operate in real time.

Comment: @sbr - haste makes waste, huh? I wasn't putting all the pieces together, and wound up with two. Thanks for combining them.

Comment: I think I solved this for myself. I wasn't thinking clearly through the steps I had to take, and finally was able to get the results I needed. Solution posted in my original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stebesplace/gYf4h/10/) shows the solution for me. It's far simpler than I had before. There was a solution given below regarding a listener plugin, which looked pretty good, but way overkill for what I needed.

```
<form id="vcForm">
    <div id="i1">100</div>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

​

```
$("#i1").keyup(function() {
    var input1 = parseFloat($("#i1").text(),10);
    var input2 = 100;
    total1 = parseFloat(input1) + parseFloat(input2);
    $("p").text(total1);
}).keyup()​
```

The value in that first DIV will be dynamic (changing via a slider). Of course, we'll see about real time updates when I expand this out functionally, but for my original question, this answered it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a Observer pattern here.

Check this for more. http://canjs.us/#can_observe

Comment: This looks interesting. Might be a bit extreme for what my needs are, but certainly I'm reading into this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

to get the text from a div and then parse it to a float, use this:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById('i1').childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```